Входящие подключения через VPN с использованием Amnezia WG
заранее извиняюсь за возможную где-то глупость, я не сетевой инженер, и очень базово понимаю, как это должно работать.
У меня есть локальная сеть с компьютерами и роутером.
адрес роутера в локальной сети - 192.168.1.1 это keenetic speedster.
адреса соответственно компьютеров - 192.168.1.*
у роутера статичный внешний ip - это 93.100.хх.хх
на него через проксирование cloudflare направлен мой домен subdomain.domain.com

A subdomain 93.100.хх.хх Proxied

(у домена domain.com - другая запись и другой адрес)
на моём роутере проброшены через NAT порты 80, 5087 и 443 на компьютер 192.168.1.3 в локальной сети - тут у меня запущено моё asp .net приложение

"CORS": {
"PolicyName": "AllowOrigin",
"AllowedHosts": [
пара десятков хостов
]

как это работает. у меня есть сайт по адресу eshe_subdomain.domain.com, который выполняет api-запрос 
например const url = 'https://subdomain.domain.com:443/api/Chats/chat';
всё отлично работает, везде подгружены сертификаты - всё окей.
эта схема настроена верно.
теперь я решил добавить в неё vpn. 
ну вернее не то чтобы решил, это у нас так обстоятельства складываются, что без него жить становится трудно.
я арендовал сервер в германии (5.61.хх.хх), внутри него приложение amnezia разворачивает собственный серверный контейнер, к которому можно через него же подключиться.
сам vpn я решил настроить прямо через роутер, настроив в keenetic speedster дополнительное подключение, подкачав какой-то плагинчик.
я загрузил файл конфига, установил дополнительный плагин для роутера - и всё работает. 
когда я перемещаю любой компьютер или телефон из своей внутренний сети в настройках роутера в "зону" дополнительного подключения (этого wg vpn) - они начинают работать через него,
через мой vpn amnezia который развёрнут в докер-контейнере на моём немецком vds.
при этом сеть между моим роутером и непосредственно amnezia-контейнером на этом vds - 10.8.1.
я так понимаю что он сам - 10.8.1.0, а мой роутер - 10.8.1.9 (это точно, этот адрес я в нём вижу)
плюс, там есть ещё какая-то сеть на самой vds вида 172. - я так понимаю что это сеть между vds и докер-контейнером.
в общем это всё тоже работает, но разумеется мой backend перестаёт быть доступным извне.
собсно, вопрос - как сделать его доступным?
первое что я должен сделать - поменять А запись на cloudflare

A backend 5.61.хх.хх (проксирование CF я пока оставил)

это я сделал.
после этого, пробросить все порты на роутере ещё раз, но уже не для моего подключения с интернетом, а для впн-подключения, второго. (имеется ввиду входящие)
это я тоже сделал.
дальше, насколько я понимаю я должен настроить роуты на vds внутрь docker-контейнера с amnezia
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:443

и потом в нём - на свой роутер по адресу 10.8.1.9
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.1.9:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.1.9:443

я тоже это сделал
там ведь не нужно отдельно подгружать сертификаты - я просто направляю траффик на свой компьютер в итоге где они все уже были настроены и я знаю, что работают.
но у меня не получается, эта схема не работает и мой backend не доступен.
curl -k из контейнера amnezia - пингует subdomain.domain.com, но с вдски снаружи контейнера - нет.
что я делаю не так? или это amnezia wg слишком хитрая? или нужно что-то ещё?
исскуственный интеллект советует запустить внутри контейнера например socat чтобы слушать 443 порт, раз он, мол не пингуется извне контейнера - но это разве так работает? мне же просто нужно маршрутизировать траффик через сетки.
у keenetic speedster есть занятная функция в "политиках подключения" - включить многопутевой режим, когда все включенные подключения в политике передают траффик. и на первый взгляд - это выглядит как то что нужно, потому что если одновременно оставить там и общее ethernet-подключение и vpn - как будто бы временами всё работает как раз так как мне бы хотелось.
вот только абсолютно не стабильно, к сожалению. я не понимаю по какому принципу - но какой нибудь 2ip может детектить у меня например местный ip - и при этом будет работать дискорд и чатжпт. через 10 минут - там будет немецкий ip ну и так далее.
бог бы с ним конечно, но с входящими подключениями тоже через какое-то время начинает происходить какая-то дурка с бесконечными дисконнектами.
Возможно, правда, если говорить про этот функционал кинетика, я тут подумал, странности со стабильностью внешних подключений больше связаны в таком случае с тем, что есть ещё 192.168.1.2 (который вне зоны с политикой впн-подключения на роутере) - к которому иногда подключается бек с 192.168.1.3. И как будто бы несмотря на то, что логи бекенда не отдают никаких ошибок подключения - возможно тормозит именно этот процесс, когда исходящее подключение с бека пытается пролезть через впн, и не находит там никакого 192Может это можно тоже прямо маршрутизацией на роутере решить?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы хотите, чтобы веб-сервер из германии пересылал бы запросы на ваш бэк в России? Если да, то я бы поднял в Германии nginx и через reverse proxy пробрасывал запросы на ваш ip. Заодно там же разместил сертификаты. Имхо, точка входа должна быть одна, и раз она теперь у вас в Германии, то пусть там и сертификаты будут

Понимаю вашу идею, и согласен - звучит она максимально логично, но на самом деле причина всей это истории немного тупее. Мне просто нужно чтобы я - мог работать на компьютере (ну и в общем, на компьютерах локальной сети) через впн, как это делаю сейчас, и при этом к некоторым его ресурсам (ну вот 443, например) оставался внешний доступ. А Германия - это просто конструкция вг впна, которая легко выстраивается с помощью амнезии.

По ссылке есть ответы на ваш вопрос https://www.opennet.ru/openforum/vsluhforumID1/89358.html  Если коротко, нужно создать доп. таблицы маршрутизации и маркировать трфик от разных шлюзов.
